# How to iteratively build F.when().otherwise logic

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm trying to programmatically build out a series of F.when().otherwise() conditional statements using pyspark. Pretty much I want to host layers of "decisions" in a dictionary, and programmatically build a series of F.when().otherwise() statements. An example of what I'm trying to achieve should make this clear...

At the moment I have this dictionary of decisions...

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

decision = {
    "first_layer": {
        "rule": F.col("col1") * 25 > 0.34,
        "outcome": 0,
    },
    "second_layer": {
        "rule": F.col("col2") * 100 > 0.34,
        "outcome": 0,
    },
    "last_layer": {
        "rule": F.col("col3") > 0.35,
        "outcome": 1,
        "termination_criteria": 0,
    },
}
```

That I could manually pass with the below in the F.when().otherwise() series...

```
rule_1 = decision["first_layer"]["rule"]
outcome_1 = decision["first_layer"]["outcome"]

rule_2 = decision["second_layer"]["rule"]
outcome_2 = decision["second_layer"]["outcome"]

rule_3 = decision["last_layer"]["rule"]
outcome_3 = decision["last_layer"]["outcome"]
termination_criteria = decision["last_layer"]["termination_criteria"]
```

I want to be able to build the below logic programatically instead of having to type it out...

```
F.when(rule_1, outcome_1).otherwise(
    F.when(rule_2, outcome_2).otherwise(
        F.when(rule_3, outcome_3).otherwise(termination_criteria)
    )
),
```

Does anybody have any suggestions as to how I could loop over the `decision` dictionary and programmatically build the F.when().otherwise() series? The idea is I want to make the construction of the F.when().otherwise() series generalisable, so I could pass in different decision dictionaries and build the conditional logic, where each decision dictionary will always have a "last_layer"

I've tried a recursive function to try and get this working, but I couldn't get it to work...

Anyone have any advice here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize Python's `reduce` function to chain `.when` statements. That would be like this

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from functools import reduce

# cond is conditional statements from `decision` dictionary
cond = reduce(lambda x, i: x.when(decision[i]['rule'], decision[i]['outcome']),  
              [i for i in decision], 
              F).otherwise(decision["last_layer"]["termination_criteria"])
```